# exec.command - CMD.exe - Query by command line

Tags: go, cmd, command-line-interface

I am with my first project. It is a small program written in GO that will run on Windows. This should make a query to free software, through a command line in the CMD.

So far I have managed to run the cmd.exe and position the terminal in the program path, but I cannot get the command line to be inserted in order to make the query. I can't find the instruction for it.

I don't know if what I'm missing is to write the query well -according to Windows- or is it a matter of better articulating the programming in Go.
I ask if you can help me. Thank you!

This is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command(
        "cmd.exe", 
        "/K",      
        "start",   
    )

         cmd.Dir = "C:/sweph"


//command line to call program: swetest64 -p2 -b1.12.1900 -n15 -s2


    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the Go code you are using, and also try with `cmd /c "command"`.

Comment: Roque, el código que utilicé está publicado al inicio. Y el que me recomendó Hossein Nazari está en mi segundo post.

Comment: Thanks for the Spanish, but lets keep in in English, please follow Adam Smith comments and edit you question instead of adding a non-answer.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "swetest64 -p2 -b1.12.1900 -n15 -s2") 

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
  log.Fatalf("run error: %v\n", err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is absolutely fine. The program `"swetest64 -p2 -b1.12.1900 -n15 -s2"` which you are calling is returning a nonzero exit code.

Any nonzero exit code is treated as an error that is printed after `cmd.Run()` call.

So there is no problem with your code. Check the program you are calling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will investigate.